# how to give file uri in build method of docusign android sdk

Tags: docusignapi

i am trying to pass uri as
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/c4611_sample_explain.pdf");
Log.e( "error" ,file.toURI().toString());/*in logcat E/error:file:/storage/emulated/0/c4611_sample_explain.pdf*/

.uri (file.toURI().toString())
.name("c4611_sample_explain.pdf")
in build method of docusign android sdk however its giving me error
11121-11121/com.example.docusignapp E/main: Unknown exception in loading document: File not found at specified URI.

tried
.uri("file:///storage/emulated/0/c4611_sample_explain.pdf")
.name("c4611_sample_explain.pdf")
also tried
.uri("file:///storage/emulated/0")
.name("c4611_sample_explain.pdf")

In android phone file is in path /storage/emulated/0/downloads

kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/c4611_sample_explain.pdf");
URI fileURI = file.toURI();
```

Then,

```
.uri(fileURI.toString());
```

Comment: I have integrated the docuSign Android SDK in my app and been able to achieve embedded signing. But it asks for the customer to login before signing the document. As its a customer facing app, we dont want them to enter the organisation docusign credentials. 
How can we skip the login or authenticate implicitly using the SDK methods or some other way?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please check the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65591633/how-can-we-skip-the-login-or-authenticate-implicitly-using-the-docusign-android/65602014#65602014